# RISCV dissassembly options numeric and no-aliases

Tags: disassembly, riscv

I cloned the riscv-tools repository (master branch) and followed the build procedure. Everything went fine.

Then I tried compiling the hello world program for a RV32IM instruction set, doing this:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -m32 -march=RV32IM -o hello hello.c -save-temps
```

I used options save-temps to keep the intermediate files. (hello.s, hello.i, hello.o)

Everything is OK so far, I can run the hello world program with:

```
spike pk hello
Hello world!
```

Now I wanted to take a look at the assembly code for this program. I did the following and I do get the assembly code into hello.dump

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -D -S -l -F  hello.o > hello.o.dump
```

Now what I would be interested to see is the assembly code without pseudo instructions and with the non ABI-register names.

It appears to be possible to get that, when I do:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump --target-help
```

I get this:

```
The following RISC-V-specific disassembler options are supported for use
with the -M switch (multiple options should be separated by commas):

numeric       Print numeric reigster names, rather than ABI names.

no-aliases    Disassemble only into canonical instructions, rather
              than into pseudoinstructions.
```

However when I try adding these options, it does not work.

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -D -S -l -F  -Mno-aliases hello.o > hello.o.dump
Unrecognized disassembler option: no-aliases

riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -D -S -l -F  -Mnumeric hello.o > hello.o.dump
Unrecognized disassembler option: numeric

riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -D -S -l -F  -Mnumeric,no-aliases hello.o > hello.o.dump
Unrecognized disassembler option: numeric
Unrecognized disassembler option: no-aliases
```

Is it a command syntax error or is it just not supported yet by the disassembler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce this and get the same error message. However, `riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump` returns 0 and the output file does contain an assembler dump without pseudoinstructions and/or with numeric register names, as requested by the option. So it seems like this is working as expected, it just also outputs an irritating error message.

The [`riscv-tools`](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools) repo has not been updated since Feb. I also tried this with a build of a more recent version of [`riscv-gnu-toolchain`](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain) and here I don't get the error message. So I'd say this is a non-critical bug that already has been fixed in `riscv-gnu-toolchain` and thus it will be fixed in `riscv-tools` as soon as `riscv-gnu-toolchain` is updated there.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, I do get the error message, but when I look at the assembler dump, the numeric register names and the non-pseudo instructions are visible in the file.

Thanks for pointing out that this is just an misleading error message beeing printed...